# Transformation of Dependent and Independent Variables

Tags: feature-engineering, preprocessing

I have a few Independent variables that's normal and a Dependent variables that's skewed , I pick **log(feature+SHIFT)** to correct skewness. The procedure I follow to get prediction is just take **exp(predictions)-SHIFT**.

Now how do I get my predictions for the following cases.

1) I have **Normal - dependent variable** and the **independent variables** are **skewed** , I transform only a **few of them** using same **log(feature+SHIFT)** where the **shifts** are **unique** for every feature.

2) Transformations on **both** dependent and independent variables **with different SHIFT values.**

Suitable code examples will be highly appreciated. Thanks